# Removing Spaces in Perl when Printing to a text file

Tags: perl, text, formatting

So I have this code in perl that parses an xml and i want the perl file to print out to the text file so that everything is in columns like so:

```
SpectrumIndex TotalIonCount Duration Spectrum 
Integer Float Float mass,abundance;mass1,abundance1;mass 2,abundance1
```

Here is the xml code:

```
<message>
       <cmd id="result_data">
          <result-file-header>
                 <path>String</path>
                 <duration>Float</duration>
                 <spectra-count>Integer</spectra-count>
          </result-file-header>
          <scan-results count="Integer">
                 <scan-result>
                 <spectrum-index>Integer</spectrum-index>
                 <time-stamp>Integer</time-stamp>
                 <tic>Float</tic>
                 <start-mass>Float</start-mass>
                 <stop-mass>Float</stop-mass>
                 <spectrum count="Integer">mass,abundance;mass1,abundance1;
                 mass2,abundance2;mass6,abundance6</spectrum>
                 </scan-result>
                 <scan-result>
                 <spectrum-index>Integer</spectrum-index>
                 <time-stamp>Integer</time-stamp>
                 <tic>Float</tic>
                 <start-mass>Float</start-mass>
                 <stop-mass>Float</stop-mass>
                 <spectrum count="Integer">mass3,abundance3;mass4,abundance4;
                 mass5,abundance5</spectrum>
                 </scan-result>
            </scan-results>
    </cmd>
</message>
```

However using the following perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl-w
#example to write to text
my $file = "gapiformat.txt";
unless(open FILE, '>'.$file) {
    die "\nUnable to create $file\n";
}
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;


 my $values= XMLin('samplegapi.xml',ForceArray => ['scan-result','result-file-header']);


my $results = $values->{'cmd'}->{'scan-results'}->{'scan-result'};
my $results1= $values->{'cmd'}->{'result-file-header'};

printf FILE ("%-s %-s %-s %s\n","SpectrumIndex","TotalIonCount","Spectrum","Duration");
for my $data (@$results) {
    my $spectrum=$data->{spectrum};
    for my $data1 (@$results1){    
    printf FILE ("%-s %-s %-s %-s\n",$data->{"spectrum-index"}, $data->{tic}, $spectrum          
->{'content'},$data1->{duration});
    }   
  }
```

It gives the following output to the text file:

```
 SpectrumIndex TotalIonCount Spectrum Duration
 Integer Float mass,abundance;mass1,abundance1;
                 mass2,abundance2;mass6,abundance6 Float
 Integer Float mass3,abundance3;mass4,abundance4;
                 mass5,abundance5 Float
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just put how many character you want in the printf:
e.g.

```
printf FILE ("%20s %20s %40s %10s\n",...)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In modern perl:

   - you use the three argument form of [`open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
   - you use `my` variables instead of bareword filehandles
   - and you output the system error message ([`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24!)) when things go wrong:

   ```
   open my $INFILE, '<', $fname
       or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";
   ```
2. You have to print line by line.  You can't print one column and then another column.
   So when you do this:

   ```
   printf FILE (
       "%-s %-s %-s %-s\n",
       $data->{"spectrum-index"},
       $data->{tic},
       $spectrum->{'content'},
       $data1->{duration}
   );
   ```

   ... then of course all that data is going to be on one line.

Comment: I'm really just trying to figure out how to get the spectrum data to be on individual lines

Comment: "\n".  For instance, "%-s \n %-s \n %-s \n".  The format string for printf() is just a regular string except the special % codes are replaced.

Comment: Why don't you post a sample of your XML file and your desired output with some actual numbers?  By the way, the desired output you posted doesn't make any sense.  I don't know if it's being rendered incorrectly by the forum software or what.  Did you proofread your post?

Comment: sorry about that i realized a better why to format the text file so i can process it later...ive also posted an example of the xml file

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out...i just used:

```
my $content=$spectrum->{'content'};
$content=~s/\s+$//g
```

and that did the trick